# Integrated webcam not detected on Thinkpad x270 under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, webcam

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad x270. Unfortunately the integrated webcam is 'typically' not detected. Cheese gives `no device found', and there is no entry for the webcam on lsusb.
Strangely, there were instants in the past where the webcam was activated, but usually it crashed after starting cheese. On one of these occasions lsusb yielded:

```
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 5986:111c Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
```

I extensively searched the web but could not find a solution of how to activate the webcam, so I am getting a bit lost. Can anyone help? I may remark that I am not a Linux expert, just an ordinary (academic) user.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/djrscally/miix-510-cameras
**Why was this so difficult?**

> There's a few problems:
>
> ```
> The cameras are powered off by default behind a PMIC called a TPS68470, identified as INT3472 in the ACPI tables. The ACPI tables
> ```
>
> don't define an I2cSerialBus2 section for the PMIC, so its driver
> never realises that it's present.
> The TPS68470 driver doesn't actually turn it on; there are 3 GPIO lines into the PMIC defined in the ACPI tables, but they're off by
> default and the PMIC driver doesn't toggle them. They're also not
> named in the ACPI tables so it's not a simple matter to determine
> which ones are the power lines and which the reset pin. In my case, 1
> and 2 were power and 0 was reset, so the chip can be turned on like
> so:
>
> $ sudo gpioset gpiochip0 122=1 143=1
>
> Before that step, neither the PMIC nor the camera's i2c interface is
> even enabled, meaning they don't show anywhere at all. Once the device
> is on, you should be able to see it using i2cdetect:

> $ sudo i2cdetect -r -y 7
>
> this will return something like:

> NU:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  a  b  c  d  e  f
> 00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0c -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 10: 10 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

> The OV2680 is at 0x10. The TPS68470 is the device at 0x48. I have no
> idea what is at 0x0c; that's one of the two possible addresses defined
> for the oc5648, but powering that chip's PMIC on reveals it to be at
> 0x36. Who cares, really. Anyway, now that the camera is turned on you
> can verify that this isn't bullshit by talking to the sensor and
> asking for its id. The OV2680 datasheet tells us that its id sits at
> register 0x300a:

> $ sudo i2ctransfer 7 w2@0x10 0x30 0x0a r2 WARNING! This program can
> confuse your I2C bus, cause data loss and worse! I will send the
> following messages to device file /dev/i2c-7: msg 0: addr 0x10, write,
> len 2, buf 0x30 0x0a msg 1: addr 0x10, read, len 2 Continue? [y/N] y
> 0x26 0x80

> That command basically says "write two bytes (being 0x30 and 0x0a) to
> bus 7 addr 0x10, then read two bytes". The two bytes we write are the
> address of the register we're interested in, and we learn that the
> value stored there is 0x26 and 0x80, I.E. 2680! We detected the chip,
> hooray. Putting that into the drivers is a bit more difficult. It
> doesn't really make sense to turn the GPIO pins for the PMIC on in
> this driver; that ought really to go into that modules driver.
> Similarly we need to get regulators and clocks that are provided by
> the PMIC. All these things require the PMIC to have drivers to provide
> them. THe kernel has gpio drivers for this PMIC already, but no
> regulator or clock ones. There were some old ones lying around on
> Intel's lts 4.14 branch so I've appropriated those and tweaked them to
> compile into the up to date kernel.